# ¿Por qué se necesita "this" en el método "set" del atributo de una clase pero no en el "return" del método get?

Tags: java

Estoy cursando una asignatura de 2º de DAM a la vez que Programación de 1º y aunque ya había aprendido algo por mi cuenta hay detalles que se me escapan.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(string newName){
        this.name = newName;
    }
}
```

Mi duda es la del título.
¿No haría falta también usar this en el getter para que devuelva el valor del atributo?

Comment: La respuesta es simple, ese setter **no** necesita el `this`. Normalmente el setter se escribiría así: `public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}`, en este caso **SI** hace falta el `this`, por qué? Porque ambas variables se llaman igual!! Cómo va a saber java a cual te refieres en cada caso? Así al escribir `this.name` estamos haciendo referencia siempre al atributo `name` de la clase mientras que al usar solo `name` estamos haciendo referencia a la variable que recibimos como parámetro del método. Por cierto, *nadie te impide poner this en el getter!* Simplemente, no hace falta.

Comment: Perfecto, entendido.
Me despistó que se usase en el ejemplo.
Agradecido!

Comment: Bienvenido. Carga siempre el código como texto, es más fácil para nosotros copiarlo si hay un problema que debamos reproducir. Esta vez fue poco código así que no fue molestia transcribirlo yo, pero la próxima puede que no tengas la misma suerte y la pregunta no será bien recibida.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre puedes acceder a los campos de una instancia a través de `this`.

Por defecto puedes acceder a los campos directamente por su nombre. Pero si una variable local se llama igual, el compilador tiene que distinguir a cual de las dos te refieres. Por lo tanto le da prioridad a la variable local y *oculta* el campo.

Solo en estas situaciones necesitas ser explícito.

En tu código no necesitas usar `this` ya que no hay otra variable ocultando `name`:

```
class Person {
    string name;
    public void setName(string newName){
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

En este otro caso sí:

```
class Person {
    string name;
    public void setName(string name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```